# Queries to SQL Server executed in parallel multiplies time of excecution

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and SQL Server 2012. I want to load data with several AJAX queries at the same time to make it faster.

I have added `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly]` attribute to my controller so that I can process all AJAX requests in parallel.

In the action I execute DB query with Linq-to-SQL. The query is quite heavy and takes about 4 seconds to execute.

The issue is that when I perform, let's say, 4 AJAX requests at a time, I'm getting response only after 16 seconds. I looked at SQL Server profiler and each request indeed takes about 16 seconds instead of 4 in that case.

I have tired to set transaction isolation level to `READUNCOMITTED` to avoid read locks with no help.

I'm not that good at SQL Server, so any help with this issue or any thoughts are very appreciated.

**EDIT:** each time I execute same query with different parameter values and `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` if that makes any difference. Recompile is needed to prevent parameter sniffing.

Comment: You can analyze the `Page Locks` with the profiler and see if the index pages are being locked.

Comment: `READUNCOMITTED` actually makes it `500ms` faster per query. So maybe the problem is in heavy query and no way to improve it when query executes in parallel.

Comment: still it should not take 16 seconds, that is suspicious to be a lock.

Comment: @Alireza, I've found that there is Sch-S lock on tables involved in query. I've tried to remove OPTION(RECOMPILE) with no effect. I'm not sure is this is the lock that causes this issue. And can't think of other way to remove such lock.

Comment: Can I see the queries? Or least some relevant parts of them? Sometimes re-ordering the operations can help reducing chances for being trapped in locks.

Comment: @Alireza, please find the query here http://1drv.ms/1rAF4iQ. It's not an issue if you cannot say what is wrong with it. I already have an idea how to make it work better. But would be nice to know why this thing happens. And thank you for your time!

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look. And it is always a pleasure to find ad solve problems for me :)